# Pass Parameters to ant target in another directory

Tags: ant

I am trying to pass parameters to an ant target in another build file in a different location . 
Here is what I did :-

```
<target name="run">

        <ant dir="../${dir}" target="package" inheritAll="false"/>
              <property name="-Darg.vendor" value="arm"/> 
              <property name="-Darg.tech"   value="tsmc40g"/>
        </ant>

</target>
```

I pass the `dir` from command line and run the `target package` from the build file there. 
I am trying to pass the parameters but it is not accepting them.

Can anyone please help me fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the command line switches :

```
<target name="run">
  <ant dir="../${dir}" target="package" inheritAll="false"/>
    <property name="arg.vendor" value="arm"/> 
    <property name="arg.tech"   value="tsmc40g"/>
  </ant>
</target>
```